# Windows Phone 8 - Keep socket open and receive data of unknown length

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, communication, tcpclient

I have socket in which I want to receive multiple messages of unknown lengths: text, media, ..

I saw how it works with Windows.Networking.Sockets and it seems that the sender should send the length first and that's not my case

I saw a few improvements in System.Net.Sockets but didn't find any events that listens for data packets receive.

My question is: do I have to check the socket every now and then for data ? is there any better implementation?

Comment: TCP 101: if you have no higher-level protocol, you cannot have any messages larger than one byte.

Comment: Do you want to save this data without having to know the application rules for parsing it?  One idea is to read a buffer full of data at a time from the socket until the sender closes the TCP sesssion.  If you want to separate the different kinds of data, you're going to have to study the various applications you want to support and parse the received data as it arrives.  Then you can know whether you've reached the end of a unit of work.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Phone 8 Approach**

Asynchronous networking operations are supported by using the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class [`ReceiveAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.sockets.socket.receiveasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method. All you need to do is properly configure the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` before making this call and you will be able raise a handler only when data has been received.

The example from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ReceivingDatafromaTCPSocketServer) shows how to perform a Read operation synchronously, but internally it is using an asynchronous pattern. If you remove the `ManualResetEvent` part from the code, then the calls will fall through, and the event will only fire when data is ready to be processed.

**Desktop / Full .NET Approach**

Use the [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead of `Socket` and you will be able to get a `NetworkStream` object which implements [`BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - an asynchronous method which will invoke a callback function only when there is new data to be read (or the remote side has closed).

- Note: the MSDN example for `BeginRead` is finished on the page for `EndRead`. Use those two code snippets together for working code.

Comment: thanks but TcpClient is not available in windows phone

Comment: @NadaNaoushi, I have added a WP8 answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select function to keep track of your open descriptors and receive the data that has arrived over the socket.